# UIButton not in the same place on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

I moved all my `UIButtons` to fit on a particular `UIImageView` and for some reason they're not matching up the to correct location as the storyboard when run on the simulator nor the iPad itself.  It's weird and I'm confused.

This is a [screenshot of it in the storyboard](http://puu.sh/25BTH/edf3d69075).

This is a [screenshot of it on the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOOfH.png).

Notice how some of circles(buttons) the titles are shown.  Why is this happening and how can I get them into the position they are in the storyboard?  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ?

Comment: Do you use something changes the size of your view like tabbar, navigationbar....?

Comment: Yeah i was using AutoLayout.  I removed it and some of my labels are only displaying 2 characters now.  But it did fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for some reason i disabled the auto layout thing on the storyboard.  But, when i reenabled it it seemed to work.  Strange bug, but the problem is fixed now.  Thanks larme, for making me aware of the auto layout thing.